# Why are numerous HTTP-header content types classified as "application?"

Tags: http-headers

What is the meaning of "application" in these content types:

```
application/java-archive
application/EDI-X12   
application/EDIFACT   
application/javascript   
application/octet-stream   
application/ogg   
application/pdf  
application/xhtml+xml   
application/x-shockwave-flash    
application/json  
application/ld+json  
application/xml   
application/zip  
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

It seems inconsistent to have text formats like JSON and XML in there, when we have this list:

```
text/css    
text/csv    
text/html    
text/javascript (obsolete)    
text/plain    
text/xml
```

Which lacks JSON but repeats XML. And we have OGG in the "application" category, while an audio category already exists:

```
audio/mpeg   
audio/x-ms-wma   
audio/vnd.rn-realaudio   
audio/x-wav
```

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is largely addressed by [RFC 2046](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2046).

In particular, `text/*`:

> The "text" media type is intended for sending material which is principally textual in form … there are many formats for representing what might
> be known as "rich text".  An interesting characteristic of many such
> representations is that they are to some extent readable even without
> the software that interprets them.  It is useful, then, to
> distinguish them, at the highest level, from such unreadable data as
> images, audio, or text represented in an unreadable form.

and

> The "application" media type is to be used for discrete data which do
> not fit in any of the other categories, and particularly for data to
> be processed by some type of application program.

---

Some document types could fall under `text/*` or `application/*`. You raised the example of XML. Compare an XHTML document (mostly plain text with some semantic markup around it) with an SVG document (mostly descriptions of lines and points often expressed as long strings of numbers of single letters).

---

> And we have OGG in the "application" category, while an audio category already exists:

[Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) is a container format, not a video format.

---

And sometimes there are just mistakes (or things that are matters of opinion).

> text/javascript (obsolete)

JavaScript isn't supposed to be human readable. So it should be under `application/*` but was initially put under `text/*`. The RFCs were updated to move it to `application/javascript` but almost nobody paid attention to that and [it was moved back](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239.html#name-text-javascript) under weight of peer pressure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This sounds like an imperfectly-adhered-to guideline. Please note that I never said OGG was a video format. I said it is an audio format (which online references claim). Further investigation reveals that it's more akin to MPEG-4, a multipurpose container.